# Good ways to slow down a test run using Robot Framework?

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

so I'm reasonably new to Robot Framework and have run into various forms of this issue a number of times now.  Essentially I create a suite of tests which eventually pass and check for the things I expect, they then go through a CI/CD pipeline and on the dedicated test runners I hit some failures.  In essence this seems to be because the test runners do things a little faster, whether due to hardware or selenium speed, it doesn't really matter.

To avoid these failures I end up adding to the tests to 'slow' them down at certain points to ensure success, basically bloating them or just being a little more protective.  So for those with more experience, how do you handle this situation?  I'd like to stick with best practice as far as I can, i.e. I'm not just using sleeps everywhere but using implicit waits, still I don't know what the best approaches are.

Here's snippet of an issue I've hit recently:

```
Wait Until Page Contains Element ${STATIC_TABLE_XPATH}/somepath 10
${image_text} = Selenium2Library.Get Element Attribute ${STATIC_TABLE_XPATH}/somepath
${second_paragraph_text} = Selenium2Library.Get Text ${STATIC_TABLE_XPATH}/somepath
```

So basically despite these being functionally correct, they pull back nothing sometimes when run on the test runners.  I figure this is because things are happening too quickly, so I added a Wait Until Page Contains Element, unfortunately the same problem still exists.  Is there a best way to handle this situation so it consistently passes?

I thought adding a wait until keyword succeeds on the expected variable value would be pretty horrible but happy to be proved wrong!

Comment: Have you tried increasing the timeout on your `Wait Until Page Contains Element` keyword call?

Comment: I don't think that would help?  It's pretty much immediately passing that stage so wouldn't have an impact?  I find the whole situation pretty weird as what I'm getting isn't impacted by Javascript, it's there from the time of page load but because there is activity on the page it must screw it up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you feel it's horrible, I think the best way to slow Selenium down is to keep polling element attribute until you get a proper variable. There is no harm in trying to something until it succeeds. If you have a bug, attribute value will never be ok. I believe *Wait Until Keyword Succeeds* keyword was made just for cases like this. I use it all the time.

Comment: thanks Pekka, it was how I initially solved the problem but thought those more familiar with Robot Framework might use something a little 'nicer.'  If this is the best way to handle the situation, then I'm happy to do it.

Comment: to go a little further, how would you solve this using Wait Until Keyword Succeeds?  Obviously Get Text will always succeed whether it returns empty or non-empty?

Comment: Make your own keyword with element_id and expected_text arguments. Then compare against Get Text output and succeed or fail

Answer (score 2):

drkthng's reasoning is correct but you don't need to write all that code... it already exists in [`ExpectedConditions`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html). A simple example

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(locator));
```

Take a look at the docs for all the available methods (there are a bunch) and how to use them.

Comment: Again I'd preferably want to achieve this with keywords, rather than a direct Selenium implementation.  If this was the case would you have any further recommendations?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by keywords... could you give an example?

Comment: As mentioned I'm using Robot Framework to solve this issue (that's what the business use.)  I can add libraries to handle more complex situations but as this is fairly simple I wanted to exercise Robot through pre-existing keywords if possible.  For my situation I figured there was a 'best practice' I was unaware of

Comment: Ah ok. Sorry, I'm not familiar with the Robot Framework so I was trying to help from the Selenium side.

Comment: no worries JeffC, thanks for the answer and trying to help me with a problem.  It's interesting to see the pure Selenium side, in honesty, I'd rather be doing it in Selenium and your solution is extremely neat and tidy.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid Sleep as much as you can.

Implicit waits are also not a solution that scales. They can hold you back big time if you are checking the "non-existence" of elements for example.

I would suggest you make good use of WebDriverWaits.

I often have to wait for certain elements or pages to display, so I wrote some methods like this:

```
public void waitUntilDisplayed(By elementLocator, int timeoutInSeconds) {
    WebDriverWait wait = (WebDriverWait)new WebDriverWait(driver, timeoutInSeconds).ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class);
    wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {

            return elementIsDisplayed(elementLocator);
        }
    });
}

public boolean elementIsDisplayed(By elementLocator) {
    if(elementExists(elementLocator)) {
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(elementLocator);
        return element.isDisplayed();
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean elementExists(By elementLocator) {
    List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(elementLocator);
    if (elements.size() < 1) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: So this would involve writing my own library or extending an existing one?  I'd only want to go down that road if absolutely necessary.  I'm not using implicit waits to check for non existence, just yet anyway.  I figured there must be a 'desirable' approach for this situation with keywords.  Waiting until a keyword succeeds after checking equality of a value seems like the current front runner but didn't seem too clean a solution